# convert system.data.linq.binary to byte[]

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I am storing bytes in a database table. When I retrieve it with Linq 2 sql I get the return type in `system.data.linq.Binary`.

I am not able to convert the `system.data.linq.binary` to byte array(`byte[]`).

How do I convert it?

```
///my datacontext

var db = new db();

//key is an value from user

var img = from i in db.images
          where i.id == key
          select i.data;
```

the `i.data` is in `linq.binary` I want it to be in `byte[]`.

I tried with `(byte[])img` but it did not work.

Comment: how did you changed the `Binary` to `byte`?

Answer (score 41):

Have you tried calling `ToArray()` on `i.data`?

```
var img = from i in db.images
      where i.id == key
      select i.data.ToArray();
```

`System.Data.Linq.Binary` has a `ToArray` method just for that purpose.

Comment: ya it dosent work man it returns System.Data.Linq.Binary[] the array of binary thats it :(

Comment: plus we hav to use it as                                             `var img = (from i in db.images
where i.id == key
select i.data).ToArray();`

Comment: The `ToArray()` call has to be on `i.data`. You are putting the call after the parentheses. That is going to get you an `IEnumerable<System.Data.Linq.Binary[]>` and then you call `ToArray` on that `IEnumerable`. I'm assuming there can only be one image with that key. Then it looks like you want `var img = (from i in db.images where i.id == key select i.data).First().ToArray();` You probably want a null check after `First()`.

Comment: +1, it worked for [others](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/e8acefbc-8dc5-4ad0-82c3-b559b343ec2a/) to

Answer (score 5):

Probably its too late by now but may help others :)

```
//testTable PK:ID, binaryData :binary(32)

public void insertDummyData()
{
    DBML.testTable v = new DBML.testTable ();
    v.ID = 1;

    System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    v.binaryData = new System.Data.Linq.Binary(encoding.GetBytes("11111111000000001111111100000000"));                                                                    

    db.testTable.InsertOnSubmit(v);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Or else, Click on the Binary field from .dbml file, open properties and then change the field type from Binary to `byte[]` as found [here](http://dotnetdaily.net/common-dotnet-exceptions/implicitly-convert-type-system-data-linq-binary-byte/)

Answer (score 4):

```
(byte[])linqBinaryField.ToArray()
```

Comment: Not just posting an answer, you could add little explanation which understand the solution better to OP and future readers as well.

Comment: Works perfectly, no further explanation needed IMHO

Comment: The type cast is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You can try MemoryStream. I wrote a function in my project to convert an image to byte array like the following:

```
    public static byte[] Image2ByteArr(string filename)
    {            
        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(getPath(filename));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        bm.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

Hope that helpful for you!

Comment: nope dude dosent wrk i am using linq to sql to "retrieve" the value and read it into byte array conversion is from System.Data.Linq.Binary to System.byte[]

Comment: This answer is not useful -- the question asks about converting a `System.Data.Linq.Bin‌​ary` to a `byte[]` but this example converts a file path to a `byte[]` representation, with a `Bitmap` in between.

Comment: The answer doesn't relate to the OP's question.  The answer contains no reference to Linq.Binary type, which is 50% of what the OP is looking for.  Please read the question properly before posting an answer.